# how to restrict user from all controllers and actions but login page when he is not loggedin in zend framework 2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication, zend-framework2

How can i simply resist users to access any controller or method if not loggedin in zend framework 2.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
public function loginAction(){
      if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {            
        $request=$this->getRequest();
        $login_email=$request->getPost('login_email');
        $login_password=md5($request->getPost('login_password'));

     $adapter=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
     $QUERY="query to be executed";
    $user=$adapter->query($QUERY, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

if($user->count()){
$result = $user->current();
if(!empty($result))
{
$user_session = new Container('user');
foreach($user->current() as $u=>$v)$user_session->offsetSet($u,$v);
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application/default', array('action'=>'memberbasic','controller' => 'account'));                    
}
}else{
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application/default', array(
'action' => 'index','controller' => 'index'));                
}
}
}
}
?>
```

I am new to zend framework . I may extends all controller from parent controller or i may add session to layout so that if session is set then user see dashboard otherwise login page or is their any other methosd to do so in zend framework. Your help will be appriciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and don't extend from a parent controller. Controller hierarchies are going to be a nightmare in the future.

As far as restricting access, You're going to want to hang a check on one of the ZF2 events (which one is up to you and your application, but onRoute, onDispatch, or onResult are fairly popular for this sort of thing)

If you're looking for a package that does a similar thing, take a peek at https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac for inspiration.

Comment: i am just a beginner in zend framework could you give the code for onDispatch event and how this event work